# Performance issues when using plt.hist() for array with 2500 rows

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, histogram

I am using `pandas`, `numpy` and `matplotlib.pyplot` to create a histogram. I have a bottleneck when using the command `plt.hist()` (NB I have done `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`)

The data (called `data`) is a DataFrame that is 2501 rows long and its `.head()` looks like this:

```
>>> print data.head()

  Step                     X
0    0  2.16261125638519e+01
1  100  2.05988670714102e+01
2  200  2.04719904741260e+01
3  300  2.02079668696942e+01
4  400  1.98093907227472e+01
```

I then use `.values` to return an array that looks like this:

```
>>> h = data['X'].values
>>> print h

['2.16261125638519e+01' '2.05988670714102e+01' '2.04719904741260e+01' ...
'1.90247338878272e+01' '1.90866656009559e+01' '1.91424583903948e+01']
```

Finally, where I am having problems, I call `plt.hist(h)` and this was still running after waiting for 10 minutes. (NB I have not performed this to completion)

Is there anyway to speed this up as I would have thought that a length of order 10^3 would not take this long to run?

UPDATE: The values of the array `h` were strings so I have changed them to floats but am having the same problem as described:

```
>>> h = h.astype(float)
>>> print h
[21.62611256 20.59886707 20.47199047 ... 19.02473389 19.0866656
 19.14245839]
```

Comment: using `%timeit` and performing `plt.hist(h)` on some randomly generated data of length 2500 gives me a time of 19.6 ms. So I don't think that is the hold-up. Perhaps you could produce a [MCVE] that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: I found the problem, I had not actually imported numpy as a package (even though I do not explicitly call it in the script) thanks for your help anyway! Once imported it runs at the expected speed.